# How can I launch "bower install" then "spring-boot:run" using Maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, bower-install

I'm a studdent and I does not understand something with Maven in my project.

I use spring-boot and angular 1 within the same repository and I need a solution to first execute a "bower install" before using the maven pluggin "spring-boot:run".

I'd to know if it's possible to customize the maven command.

I use IntelliJ and all I do is pressing the start button in my main class

```
package fr.studionline;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class StudionlineBackApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudionlineBackApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The bower_components directory is in another directory than the main class as described in the picture below :
[tree view of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN50k.png)

Thanks in advance if you can help me understand how it work.

I will respond to any questions if there is something missing in my question.

**UPDATE:**

I did try the front-end-maven pluggin with this pom configuration :

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Use the latest released version:
                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                <version>1.4</version>


                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bower install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bower</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/static</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and this was what happend when I execute the command frontend:bower

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building studionline-back 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:bower (default-cli) @ studionline-back ---
    [INFO] Running 'bower install' in C:\Antoine\Ecole\Projet\ProjetAnu_5A\studionline-back\src\main\resources\static
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.071 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-06T17:59:58+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/155M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-

    plugin:1.4:bower 
    (default-cli) on project studionline-back: Failed to run task: 'bower install' failed. 
    java.io.IOException: 

Cannot run program "C:\Antoine\Ecole\Projet\ProjetAnu_5A\studionline-back\src\main\resources\static\node\node.exe" 
(in directory "C:\Antoine\Ecole\Projet\ProjetAnu_5A\studionline-back\src\main\resources\static"): 

    CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable -> [Help 1]

    [ERROR] 

    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

    [ERROR] 

    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

        Process finished with exit code 1
```

But I still doesn't understand how to launch it with Intellij. Should I do mvn run instead of clicking on the "Run" button ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `frontend-maven-plugin`. In particular it has a [bower runner](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md#running-bower).

```
<execution>
    <id>bower install</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>bower</goal>
    </goals>

    <configuration>
        <!-- optional: The default argument is actually
        "install", so unless you need to run some other bower command,
        you can remove this whole <configuration> section.
        -->
        <arguments>install</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Check the "Optional Configuration" section to see how to configure your front end directory. In your case:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <!-- optional -->
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/static</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```